# If there is a value in an entire column (minus header), alert user wrong file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro taking two spreadsheets and performing a look up.  I need to be able to take the value selected by the user from a combobox (ComboBox1.value), and assign a column reference to then check to see if the column is empty, before proceeding.  This is to prevent the user from selecting a month column within a spreadsheet, and providing an update for a month that has already been updated. I will then alert them, and they can choose how to proceed.

The combobox contains a list of all 12 months.  I need to set a value to be the column reference for their selection, and if that column is blank (starting from A2 to last entry in column, or if there is any value in any cell starting at row 2 to end.. whichever makes the most sense), alert them.

This sheet has over 20K rows. I can't pick just one to reference, as it is plausible it could have blanks, thus why I am checking for a value in entire column.

I for the love of Pete, in all my newbie glory, after searching to the interwebz, cannot make this happen...

Code below is not giving an error, but it also not working properly. I have a test sheet with values in it for April, and it doesn't alert, it goes to next action.

My block of code where I am trying to do this looks like ...

```
Dim UpdateMonthColumn As String

If ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "January" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "U"
ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "February" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "W"
ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "March" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "Y"
ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "April" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "C"
ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "May" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "E"
ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "June" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "G"
ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "July" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "I"
ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "August" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "K"
ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "September" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "M"
ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "October" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "O"
ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "November" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "Q"
ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "December" Then
UpdateMonthColumn = "S"
End If

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(UpdateMonthColumn)) = 0 Then

'If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Sheet 1[UpdateMonthColumn]")) <> 0 Then
Msgbox12 = Msgbox("The column you will place the ABC Count within for " &   
ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1 & "is not empty." & vbCr & " Do you still 
wish to proceed with an update for " & ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1 & "?" 
& vbCr & "Select Yes to proceed and update with new values." & vbCr 
& "Select No to return to drop down list and chose a different month." & 
vbCr & "Select Cancel to return to ABC Matrix Main Menu.", vbQuestion Or 
vbYesNoCancel, "ABC Matrix Macro")
If Msgbox12 = vbYes Then GoTo SelectFile2:
If Msgbox12 = vbNo Then ActiveWorkbook.Close
    GoTo SelectMonth:
If Msgbox12 = vbCancel Then
    Msgbox "ABC Count update cancelled by user!" & vbCr & vbCr & "Returning 
    to ABC Matrix Macro Main Menu.", vbCritical, "ABC Matrix Macro Alert!"
     With ABCMatrixMainMenu
     .StartUpPosition = 0
     .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
     .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
     .Show
    Exit Sub
  End With
 End If
Else
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to assign a value stored from my variable in a syntax that will work, to say check this column (UpdateMonthColumn) and if there is any value from Row 2 to last row, that my message box statements can be built to operate around.  Either using a statement that if nothing is in row 2 to last row, or doing the opposite (if there is any value in column (outside of header in row 1).  The above does not error, but does not work. It passes right through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim rng As Range, sht As WorkSheet

Set sht = thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1")

'select case is cleaner than a long If Then block
Select Case ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value
    Case "January": UpdateMonthColumn = "U"
    Case "February": UpdateMonthColumn = "W"
    Case "March": UpdateMonthColumn = "Y"
    '...etc
End Select


Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2,UpdateMonthColumn), _
                    sht.Cells(sht.rows.count, UpdateMonthColumn))
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
    'OK
End If
```

Comment: Question...  at the time this is to run, I have two workbooks open.  One that contains the macro itself (I can't put it in a personal workbook, I have to ship it out to a few users and they want it as a separate file), and the one I call open from the macro that upon opening, that I want to check to see if it is blank.  I may be wrong, but doesn't thisworkbook always reference the macroworkbook?  I may be wrong, forgive me... I'm still in the learning curve.

Comment: If not `ThisWorkbook` then maybe use `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: Thank you :) Will give it a go.

Comment: FWIW - If `UpdateMonthColumn` was declared as `Long` instead of `String`, the `Select Case` can be replaced with the one line  `UpdateMonthColumn = 3 + 2 * ((8 + Month(CDate("1 " & ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value & " 2000"))) Mod 12)`  (The `Select Case` will be easier to understand though! :D)

Comment: @Tim Williams it is giving me a syntax error on the Select Case ABCMatrixMonthSelect.Combobox1.value =

Comment: @SharePoint0508 That trailing `=` shouldn't be there (I have edited the answer for Tim)